# Проверьте на ошибки

Tags: пунктуация

Его  сын Саша,   двоюродный брат Алеши Пешкова. Злой и хитрый. Саша сын Михаила тоже двоюродный брат Алеши, тихий  и ленивый. Катерина двоюродная сестра Алеши, дочь дяди Михаила. 
     Алеша Пешков отличался тем, что он был добрым, хорошим мальчиком, и   тем,  что он понимал боль других, он всегда ставал на защиту слабых. Дед с сыновьями  были злыми, любили жестоко подшучивать над бедными. Из-за них члены их семьи и те, кто служим им всю свою жизнь пострадали. Им все равно, что чувствуют другие, лишь бы получить для себя выгоду.  А Каширины не любили людей, которые сильно отличались от них. Этим отличался Пешков от Кашириных. 
     Бабушку Алеши звали Акулина Ивановна Каширина.  После смерти отца  она стала самым лучшим человеком в его жизни. Она любила мир таким, каким он есть. Искренности и честности  Алеша научился именно у бабушки. У нее были  темные, красивые глаза, темные длинные волосы и  доброе лицо. Ее характер: добрая женщина, любила рассказывать истории, трудолюбивая. Она всегда была  довольна своей жизнью. Каждый раз говорила «Как хорошо все!». Это меня больше всего удивляет, я впервые встретила такого терпеливого, прощающего человека, который утверждает, что все просто отлично! Бабушка хорошо знала деда, она не боялась его, в отличии от других. Если дед был не прав, то она всегда защищала его.

Comment: Форум не выполняет д/з.

Comment: Это не д/з, мне сказали,что у меня не раставленны запятые, и что есть там где их не доллжно быть

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Его сын Саша, двоюродный брат Алеши Пешкова, злой и хитрый. Саша, сын Михаила, тоже двоюродный брат Алеши, тихий и ленивый. Катерина, двоюродная сестра Алеши, дочь дяди Михаила.

Алеша Пешков отличался тем, что он был добрым, хорошим мальчиком, и тем, что он понимал боль других, он всегда вставал на защиту слабых. Дед с сыновьями были злыми, любили жестоко подшучивать над бедными,  из-за чего члены их семьи и те, кто служим им всю свою жизнь,  всегда страдали. Кашириным было все равно, что чувствуют другие, они стремились лишь получить выгоду  для себя. И они не любили людей, которые сильно отличались от них, в том числе Алешу Пешкова.

Бабушку Алеши звали Акулина Ивановна Каширина. После смерти отца она стала самым лучшим человеком в его жизни. Она любила мир таким, каким он есть. Искренности и честности Алеша научился именно у бабушки. У нее были темные красивые глаза, темные длинные волосы.

Бабушка была добрая, трудолюбивая, любила рассказывать разные истории и  всегда была довольна своей жизнью. Каждый раз говорила: «Как хорошо все!» Это меня больше всего удивляет, я впервые встретила такого терпеливого, прощающего всех человека, который утверждал, что все просто отлично!

Бабушка хорошо знала деда, она не боялась его, в отличии от других. И даже когда дед был не прав, она всегда защищала его.

Answer (score 1):

Джина, обратите внимание на те места в Вашем тексте, которые просто необходимо было исправить.

1. "ставал на защиту". Правильно: "вставал на защиту" или "становился на защиту".
2. "те, кто служим им всю свою жизнь пострадали". Служим - описка. Придаточное предложение "кто служил им всю свою жизнь" нужно выделить запятыми. Правильно: ""те, кто служил им всю свою жизнь, пострадали"
3. "Им все равно". Рассказ составлен в прошедшем времени, поэтому правильно: "Им было все равно"
4. "Этим отличался Пешков от Кашириных". Совершенно непонятно, чем именно отличался, каким таким "этим".
5. "темные, красивые глаза" - неоднородные определения, запятая не ставится. Правильно: "темные красивые глаза"
6. "Ее характер: добрая женщина, любила рассказывать истории, трудолюбивая." Из всего перечисленного только доброта является чертой характера. Правильно: "Черты ее характера: доброта, оптимизм, ..."
7. "Если дед был не прав, то она всегда защищала его". "Если" определяет некое условие и не сочетается с "всегда". "То" - стилистически не очень хорошо. Правильно: "Она всегда защищала его, даже если он был не прав."

А также советую, взяв за основу вариант, предложенный @Sibylla, внести некоторые стилистические улучшения:

(1)

Базовый вариант:

Алеша Пешков отличался тем, что **он** был добрым, хорошим мальчиком, и тем, что **он** понимал боль других, **он** всегда вставал на защиту слабых.

Мой вариант:

Алеша Пешков отличался тем, что был добрым, хорошим мальчиком, и тем, что понимал боль других. Он всегда вставал на защиту слабых.

(2)

Базовый вариант:

После смерти отца она стала самым **лучшим человеком в его жизни.**

Мой вариант:

После смерти отца она стала самым важным человеком в его жизни (или: самым близким ему человеком).

(3)

Базовый вариант:

Она любила мир таким, **каким** он есть.

Мой вариант:

Она любила мир таким, какой он есть.

(4)

Базовый вариант:

Бабушка была **добрая, трудолюбивая.**

Мой вариант:

Бабушка была доброй, трудолюбивой.